# Multiple abstracts in one document

Tags: abstract

I would like to create a document with multiple abstracts for a conference. Below, there is code that produces only a single abstract. How can I produce several abstracts using this code?

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%%%%%%%PAGE FORMAT -  PLEASE DO NOT MODIFY!!!!
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\pagestyle{myheadings} \topmargin =-20pt \marginparwidth = 45pt
\evensidemargin = -15pt \oddsidemargin = -15pt \textheight = 670pt
\textwidth = 500pt \linespread{1.2}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}
\newtheorem{myth}{Teorema}[section]
\newtheorem{mylem}{Lema}[section]
\newtheorem{mypro}{Proposi\c c\~ao}[section]
\newtheorem{mydef}{Defini\c c\~ao}[section]
\newtheorem{myrem}{Observa\c c\~ao}[section]
\newtheorem{mycor}{Corol\'ario}[section]
\newtheorem{myex}{Exemplo}[section]
\newcommand{\cqd}{\hspace{10pt}\fbox{}}
\newcommand{\cqdf}{\hspace{10pt}\rule{5pt}{5pt}}
%
\begin{document}
 %
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 %
 %%%%% PAGE HEADER - PLEASE DO NOT MODIFY!!!
 %
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 \pagestyle{empty} %%
 \title{
 \vspace{-1in}\parbox{\linewidth}{\footnotesize\noindent {\sc\bf
 Conference}
 \newline
 {\sc \bf Universidade}
 \newline
 \bf Cidade - data}
 \newline\newline
 %%
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% END OF THE HEADER %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 %
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 %%% WRITE THE TITLE IN THE FOLLOWING COMMAND WITH
 %%% lower case (minuscule) letters!
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 %
 {\sc Title}
 %
 \author{\sc
 Autor \thanks{Departament, University,\, email: } }}
 
 %
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 %% DO NOT FILL THE COMMAND \date{} BELOW, LET IT EMPTY!!
 %% PLEASE, KEEP IN THE TEXT THE COMMANDS \maketitle AND \thispagestyle{empty}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 \date{}
 \maketitle \thispagestyle{empty} \vspace{-10pt}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 %
Abstract
```

Comment: note commands `\sc` and `\bf` have not been defined by default in latex since 1993, although `article` class defines the mfor compatibility with documents from before that, but if you do use them they do not combine `\sc\bf` is the same as `\bf` it does not denote bold small caps. It is hard to answer your question as the commands you show are not suitable for an abstract collection, you do not want `\author` and `\maketitle` for a collection of abstracts by different authors, just set each absract as (say) a new `\section`

Answer (score 2):

Use `\begin{abstract} ... \end{abstract}` environment as many times as you want.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
    \usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
    \usepackage{lipsum} % <-- To create dummy text
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %
    %%%%%%%PAGE FORMAT -  PLEASE DO NOT MODIFY!!!!
    %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \pagestyle{myheadings} \topmargin =-20pt \marginparwidth = 45pt
    \evensidemargin = -15pt \oddsidemargin = -15pt \textheight = 670pt
    \textwidth = 500pt \linespread{1.2}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    
    \renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}
    \newtheorem{myth}{Teorema}[section]
    \newtheorem{mylem}{Lema}[section]
    \newtheorem{mypro}{Proposi\c c\~ao}[section]
    \newtheorem{mydef}{Defini\c c\~ao}[section]
    \newtheorem{myrem}{Observa\c c\~ao}[section]
    \newtheorem{mycor}{Corol\'ario}[section]
    \newtheorem{myex}{Exemplo}[section]
    \newcommand{\cqd}{\hspace{10pt}\fbox{}}
    \newcommand{\cqdf}{\hspace{10pt}\rule{5pt}{5pt}}
    %
    \begin{document}
     %
     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     %
     %%%%% PAGE HEADER - PLEASE DO NOT MODIFY!!!
     %
     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     \pagestyle{empty} %%
     \title{
     \vspace{-1in}\parbox{\linewidth}{\footnotesize\noindent {\sc\bf
     Conference}
     \newline
     {\sc \bf Universidade}
     \newline
     \bf Cidade - data}
     \newline\newline
     %%
     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% END OF THE HEADER %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     %
     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     %%% WRITE THE TITLE IN THE FOLLOWING COMMAND WITH
     %%% lower case (minuscule) letters!
     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     %
     {\sc Title}
     %
     \author{\sc
     Autor \thanks{Departament, University,\, email: } }}
     
     %
     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     %% DO NOT FILL THE COMMAND \date{} BELOW, LET IT EMPTY!!
     %% PLEASE, KEEP IN THE TEXT THE COMMANDS \maketitle AND \thispagestyle{empty}
     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     \date{}
     \maketitle \thispagestyle{empty} \vspace{-10pt}
     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     %
    \begin{abstract}
      \lipsum[1]
    \end{abstract}
    
    \begin{abstract}
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{abstract}
    \end{document}
```

The output is-
[image]

Answer (score 0):

(With apologies in case the answer is not helpful, I'm a newbie here)

To elaborate on the suggestion by David Carlisle, "just set each abstract as (say) a new \section":

The closest case I can think of is a PhD thesis that requires abstracts in two languages. They are encoded as **different sections**.

Comment: It is always a good idea to make answers a bit more descriptive, for instance by applying your suggestion to the code from the question.